# Modify one specific field of Exif information of image file using piexifjs in Node.js

Tags: node.js, orientation, exif

I am developing web application using Node.js that involves some image processing. In my application, I need to modify the Exif information of an image (Orientation), only one field. And then I want all the other information remains the same. I am using [this library](http://piexifjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample.html).

I am using this code

```
var filename1 = "test.jpg";
                var filename2 = "out1.jpg";

                var jpeg = fs.readFileSync(filename1);
                var data = jpeg.toString("binary");

                var zeroth = {}; //exifData.image;//{};//exifData.image//{};
                var exif = {};
                var gps = {};

                zeroth[piexif.ImageIFD.Make] = "Make";
                zeroth[piexif.ImageIFD.XResolution] = [777, 1];
                zeroth[piexif.ImageIFD.YResolution] = [777, 1];
                zeroth[piexif.ImageIFD.Software] = "Piexifjs";
                exif[piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeOriginal] = "2010:10:10 10:10:10";
                exif[piexif.ExifIFD.LensMake] = "LensMake";
                exif[piexif.ExifIFD.Sharpness] = 777;
                exif[piexif.ExifIFD.LensSpecification] = [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]];
                gps[piexif.GPSIFD.GPSVersionID] = [7, 7, 7, 7];
                gps[piexif.GPSIFD.GPSDateStamp] = "1999:99:99 99:99:99";
                var exifObj = {"0th":zeroth, "Exif":exif, "GPS":gps};
                var exifbytes = piexif.dump(exifObj);

                var newData = piexif.insert(exifbytes, data);
                var newJpeg = new Buffer(newData, "binary");
                fs.writeFileSync(filename2, newJpeg)
```

What above code doing is creating the new file and Exif information. Then insert that new Exif information into the new image file, but I do not want it, because I am modifying only one field. I only want to change orientation only and maintain the other fields. So, I tried doing something like this:

```
var filename1 = "test.jpg";
                var filename2 = "out1.jpg";

                var jpeg = fs.readFileSync(filename1);
                var data = jpeg.toString("binary");

                var zeroth = {}; //exifData.image;//{};//exifData.image//{};
                var exif = {};
                var gps = {};
                zeroth[piexif.ImageIFD.Orientation] = 1;

                var exifObj = {"0th":zeroth, "Exif":exif, "GPS":gps};
                var exifbytes = piexif.dump(exifObj);

                var newData = piexif.insert(exifbytes, data);

                fs.writeFileSync(filename2, newJpeg)
```

But the attempt was not working. So, how can I modify only one specific field (Orientation) and maintain other fields of Exif data of an image file using piexifjs?